# why is this laurel hedge still dying

Tags: plant-health, watering, roots, hedge

This laurel was dying, leaves going brown. Soil a bit dry, watered it loads, a week and a half later still dying. Googled it, some results said probably drought and some said waterlogged roots!

So I would continue to water it lots as that's what it looks like it needs, but am I at risk of "drowning" it???

Location Bognor Regis, UK (south coast) https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Bognor+Regis/

Age of hedge - planted 1 month ago by a landscaper

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you in the world? How long have you had this hedge?

Comment: What kind of soil does your garden have?